# How to programatically get the fragments called in an RTFtemplate?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to programmatically find the fragments that are called by each rtftemplate.
So, for example in the figure, I would need to get the "GlossaryTermsAcronyms" fragment for the H2_terms_acronyms template.
[image]

I can't seem to find any query or script solution to do this. But this should be possible, right?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that is (almost) impossible.

The information is stored in the `t_documents.bincontent` column. It is binary encoded RTF.
Somewhere in that RTF there should be a reference to the templates fragments that are used.

If you can figure out how to decode the bincontent to get to the actual RTF code of your template, you might have a chance.

Binary fields in EA are usually stored as a zipped text file.

In case the field is included in an xml file (or xml string in the database), it will be base64 encoded.

Comment: There are few exceptions (at least one): picture files in t_image are just the image blob without zip (which is a rare case where EA engineers made sense).